# Blazor - Read a cookie value in pre-rendering and OnInitializeAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, httpcontext, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor Server .NET 8 web application that uses/calls a DLL for various tasks including retrieving and reading the value of a cookie. Basically, the DLL used HttpContext, which is not always available in Blazor.

Thank you,
Max

I therefore tried to use JSRuntime, but I have to retrieve the cookie in the page initialization, so this solution isn't possible.

I tried using HttpContext only when it's available (pre-rendered) and saving a static variable from a class in my DLL, hoping that it would persist too, but that didn't work.

I also tried using the "Scoped" feature, without success.

I can't see any other solution at the moment... help!

The crazy thing is that I'm able to access my cookie during pre-rendering, my DLL is doing its job well. Then on the second page execution, the HttpContext disappears and I don't know how to retrieve the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext is always available using IHttpContextAccessor in blazor.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor

@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized(){
        var mycookies = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, when pre-rendering, I have my HttpContext
After the pre-rendering, the code is running a second time, and I dont have HttpContext (NullException)

Comment: Use of IHttpContextAccessor is now highly discouraged. Use the new HttpContext cascading parameter instead. It’s available in the root component. stackoverflow.com/questions/77353050/httpcontext-in-net-8-0